# Radio button changing textblocks

Tags: c#, visual-studio-express

When I click on my radio buttons I would like the textblock1.text to update. This is what I have and thought it would work but it doesnt. This is for visual studio 2010express

```
    private void changetitle(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (radioButton1.IsChecked==true)
            textBlock1.Text = "Celsius";
            textBlock3.Text = "Farenheight"; 

        if(radioButton2.IsChecked==true)
            textBlock1.Text = "Inch";
            textBlock3.Text = "cm"; 
    }
```

this on the otherhand does work but ONLY after I press my button (which I want the title to change before hand so the user knows what they are entering (inches or cm and where they should put them)

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        if (radioButton1.IsChecked == true) 
        {
            textBlock1.Text = "Celsius";
            textBlock3.Text = "Farenheight";
            CalcDegrees(); 
        }
        if (radioButton2.IsChecked == true)
        {
            textBlock1.Text = "Inch";
            textBlock3.Text = "cm"; 
            Calcinch2cm(); 
        }

    }
```

Any input or help would be greatly appreciated please, thank you. V/r

Comment: Is this for a windows or web app?

Comment: for android made through visual studio express 2010

Comment: Is the RadioButton part of the `System.Windows.Forms` class or the `System.Web.UI.WebControls` class?  Or something else entirely?

Comment: As far as I know, Visual Studio doesn't come with any libraries for Android development. If you're using some third-party SDK, you'll need to tell us what it is.

Comment: its C# Phone Application in visual studio 2010 express for windows phones

Answer (score 2):

You have to wire an event handler to the `onChanged` event for the radio buttons.  In this event handler, you can change the text.

Also, if this is an ASP.NET application, insure that the radio buttons have `runat="server"` otherwise the event wiring will not function.